# Running a bash find with file cp parameter error python script

Tags: bash

I'd like to copy a file_list to another location. This is being called in a python script.  I have

```
find <sourceaddress> -exec cp '{}' <destaddress> | .* rm
```

but it tells me an exact parameter is missing.  It runs though it gives a prompt from the command line and from the script just does nothing.

Comment: @rkta This is three commands to find the files I want and to copy them.

Comment: `-exec` takes all the subsequent parameters as the command line to exec. It expects a literal `;` as argument to know where the command to exec ends.

Comment: How can we tell you how to make `| .* rm` work if you don't tell us what you think `| .* rm` is supposed to mean to the shell? We know bash as the interpreter actually executes it; we don't know bash-as-someone-imagined-it-to-be -- so English does much better than broken code at communicating intent.

Comment: BTW, the "Complex Actions" section of [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) is generally a good resource.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing "\;" at the end. I am not sure what the .* rm does. Assuming you want to remove the files you can use the 'mv' command instead of 'cp'.

For copying files only from one directory to another ,

```
find <srcdirectory> -exec cp '{}' <destdirectory> \;
```

If you want to move the files, use 'mv' instead use below.

```
find <srcdirectory> -exec mv '{}' <destdirectory> \;
```

Comment: @badroot I don't have the '| .* rm' working though.  'find <srcaddress> -exec cp -r '{}' <destaddress> \;' does work

Comment: If you still want to use cp and rm, you could do just this: `find <srcdirectory> -exec mv '{}' <destdirectory> \; -exec rm '{}' \;`